# Variable while calling a function

Tags: python-3.x, class

I have a maybe silly question. Let's take the example below.

```
class Myclass():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def function_1(self):
        print("1")

    def function_2(self):
        print("2")

variable = "1"

if variable == "1":
    Myclass().function_1()
if variable == "2":
    Myclass().function_2()
```

Would it be possible to replace the "if" conditions with something like:

```
Myclass().function_{0}().format(variable)
```

If yes, how ?

Comment: `d = {"1": Myclass().function_1, "2":Myclass().function_2}` and `d["1"]()` ... but.... why? And thos would all be different Instances of Myclass ...

Comment: Because I have a lot of functions, and depending on one variable I need to call one or the other... So: just to avoid 200 if conditions. :)

Comment: `def DoIt(variable): if variable == "1": self.Do_1() elif ...` + `Myclass().DoIt("1")` with your classmethod kindof a facade for features ... but my guess would be thats a problem by design on your part to begin with :)

Comment: Thank you Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to dynamically get a method from its name:

```py
getattr(Myclass(), 'function_{0}'.format(variable))()
```

Comment: That's great, it's what I was looking for! Thank you @Mueinik :)